# XSLT Creating a variable to count number of iteration inside for-each

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I don't know how can I create a variable and assi.

I'm new to using XSLT and I have an XML file that file have some nodes that nodes have some child I need to count those child using for-each (every for-each I need to increment that count by 1 and also my counter that I want start from 1)

I don't know how can I create an variable and assign it to value 1.

Here is example about what I need:

```
<root>
  <body>
    <sec id="sec1">
      <!--Parent also can contain no sub element or also can contain a free text-->
      <p></p>
      <p>some free text</p>
      <p>
        <!--Nodes I want to count it-->
        <childNodes></childNodes>
        <childNodes></childNodes>
        <childNodes></childNodes>
        <childNodes></childNodes>
        <childNodes></childNodes>
        <!--Nodes I want to count it-->
      </p>
    </sec>
    <sec id="sec2">
      <p>
        <!--Nodes I want to count it-->
        <childNodes></childNodes>
        <childNodes></childNodes>
        <childNodes></childNodes>
        <childNodes></childNodes>
        <childNodes></childNodes>
        <!--Nodes I want to count it-->
      </p>
      <p>
        <!--Nodes I want to count it-->
        <childNodes></childNodes>
        <childNodes></childNodes>
        <childNodes></childNodes>
        <childNodes></childNodes>
        <childNodes></childNodes>
        <!--Nodes I want to count it-->
      </p>
    </sec>
  </body>
</root>
```

The output I need like that

```
<root>
    <childNodes>
        <count> 
            The count of all childNodes
        </count>
    </childNodes>
</root>
```

Can you help to solve that problem, thanks in advance

Comment: Variables cannot be incremented once set in XSLT, so your suggested approach will not work. Instead, can you edit your question to show the output you expect, please, so that an alternate approach can be suggested, possibly using `xsl:number` or `position()`. Thank you.

Comment: If you are looking to get the count of `<childNodes>` that are child elements of `<p>` then you can try using the `count()` function. `count(p/*)` will give the count of child elements of `<p>`.

Comment: thank you for your valuable comment, I edited the question @TimC

Comment: @AniketV that what I need, can you write it as an answer and I mark it as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the shared output XML, there are 2 possible output options. Either get the total count of `<childNodes>` in the XML or get separate counts for `p/childNodes`.

Total count of `<childNodes>` can be fetched using below template

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" > 
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <childNodes>
                <count><xsl:value-of select="count(//childNodes)" /></count>
            </childNodes>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<root>
    <childNodes>
        <count>15</count>
    </childNodes>
</root>
```

If you need separate counts

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" > 
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:if test="*">
            <childNodes>
                <count><xsl:value-of select="count(*)" /></count>
            </childNodes>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<root>
    <childNodes>
        <count>5</count>
    </childNodes>
    <childNodes>
        <count>5</count>
    </childNodes>
    <childNodes>
        <count>5</count>
    </childNodes>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication58
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement root = new XElement("root");
            XElement body = new XElement("body");
            root.Add(body);


            for (int id = 1; id <= 10; id++)
            {
                XElement newSec = new XElement("sec",
                    new XAttribute("id", "sec" + id.ToString()),
                    XElement.Parse("<!--Parent also can contain no sub element or also can contain a free text--><p></p>"),
                    new XElement("p", "some free text")
                    );
                body.Add(newSec);
                XElement nodes = new XElement("p");
                newSec.Add(nodes);

                for (int childCount = 1; childCount <= 10; childCount++)
                {
                    XElement newChild = new XElement("childNods", new XAttribute("id", "node" + childCount.ToString()),
                        "Child Text"
                     );
                    nodes.Add(newChild);

                }

            }


        }

    }
}
```